# Router.js won't route

Tags: node.js

I want to route an URL formatted with slashes in nodeJS. I want this:

http://localhost/a

But, when I goto the page, I got a 404 not found, why ?

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/a'), function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Whatever you wish to send \n');
}
```

Comment: This is a router.js route and not express

Comment: do you need to specify a port? `80` would normally give you a different error unless you ran it under `sudo`, maybe you need to go to `localhost:8080/a`, where `8080` is the port number you make `router` listen to.

Comment: It's not that because localhost:80 works perfectly. But localhost:80/a does not work.

Comment: The port you listen to implicitly when you go to `localhost/a` is `80`. Was just a thought, I haven't worked with `router.js` before.

Comment: Haven't worked with `router.js` either, but according to https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/, there is no `router.get(...)` code example. Is that THE `router.js` you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the framework you are using, I think your syntax is wrong.

IMHO it should be:

```
router.get('/a', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Whatever you wish to send \n');
})
```